# all publish requests are stuck on "Ready to transport" status

Tags: tridion-2011

I am new to tridion and trying to setup a new instance of tridion 2011.  I was able to successfully publish all my requests to file system and broker db.  Suddenly it stopped publishing  and all requests are stuck in "Ready to transport" mode.

I have already gone through many related threads on this forum, but could not sort out the problem.  I am using Widows server 2008, with Jre 1.6 (32 bit and 64 bit both installed). Any pointer to finding the issue will  be appreciated.

Comment: Hi User2447640 - you might be better asking this and any future Tridion questions on http://tridion.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

First thing to check is if your transport service is running.

Second thing I would look at is the config files to make sure the transport service is looking in the same directory that the publisher is storing them. Then see if files are being dropped in the transactions folder on the CM machine.

Comment: Thanks for you response Chris. After trying all suggestions, ultimately reinstalled the tridion and now its working. Not sure what was wrong with it.

Answer (score 2):

In our environment this issue arose due to a change in the SSL ciphers supported on our Content Deployer server. We are using the SSHFTP transport protocol and for security reasons the RC-4 cipher suite that had been supported by the CD server was no longer supported. We logged a case with SDL support and they issued Hotfix CD_2011.1.2.2350 which adds support for the stronger ciphers.

Unfortunately, the logs gave absolutely no indication of the issue, even with TRACE level logging.

So if you face this issue and you're using SSHFTP and the other solutions don't work for you, maybe this will help.